# Simple transfer from contract not working

Tags: address.transfer

this is very basic but i just want to test the transfer function. I load the contract with the constructor with 1 eth, then when i click the transfer function 0 wei is transferred. I understand this contract isn't very secure or good. But I just want to get this simple transfer out to an address to demonstrate what can be done.

My below code is as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.20;

contract Escrow {

    address public a;
    address public b;
    uint balance;



    constructor() public payable {
        a = msg.sender;
        b = 0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c;
        balance = address(this).balance;

    }

    function payoutToSeller() payable public returns(bool) {
        if (msg.sender == a) {
            b.transfer(balance);
            }
        }

     function getData() public constant returns (uint) {
         return balance;
     }

}
```

Comment: you got an issue or what? I just tried it on remix and it works well, remember to send the eth when you create the instance of the contract

Comment: it's not transferring any wei in the contract, the recipient does not receive anything.

Comment: because when you create the instance you have to set the value since the constructor is payable. If not the default would be 0.

Answer (score -1):

It works well, the balance of the contract is transfered.

Your logical mistake is that you don't update the balance after transfering, so it should be

```
    if (msg.sender == a) {
        b.transfer(balance);
        balance = 0;
        }
    }
```

You were probably calling `payoutToSeller` then checking the balance with `getData` to see if it was zero.